# UnsafeMutablePointer.null() does not work? (Is unavailable?)

Tags: swift

In Swift, to get a null, I used UnsafeMutablePointer.null() but this did not work. Xcode says it is unavailable and I should use nil literal instead which gives me another error message. Do you have a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some context. Where do you need the null pointer? Show your code and the exact error messages.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon this post while trying to answer this question myself, and I found that this worked for me

```
let nullPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(nil) // nil is the null pointer
```

Comment: This answer does nothing different than `var nullPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>? = nil` or simply passing `nil` as the parameter where an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>?` is expected based on documentation.